# To find an element with nearest lower and greater value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, search

I have two sorted matrices A and B. For all values in column 1 of A, how do I find nearest lower and greater value in matrice B? (no treshold)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Publish your code so others can help you correct it.

Comment: related question: [How to catch the index of immediate greater number in other matrix?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18813363/1336150)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `interp1`, but in the opposite way it's normally used.  Consider your B matrix a look-up table.  You're trying to look up the index of an element given it's value.  For example:

```
% Sample data
B = sort(rand(10,1));
A = sort(rand(5,1));

idx = interp1(B, 1:size(B), A, 'linear', 'extrap');
```

idx will be a double-precision value that shows the location of each element of A in B.  2.2, for instance, says that the value is between element 2 and element 3.  In fact, it's 20% of the way from element 2 to element 3.  So `floor(idx)` is the lower element, and `ceil(idx)` is the higher.

Caveats: duplicate elements in B will create a problem.  And the edge conditions might be messy.  You'll have to work those out yourself.  See what happens with an A element that's outside the range of B.